# Adding any character (an * ) every time the text breaks the line

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

i would like to make a text area where the text gets indexed with a * and the number of the line.
This is an example of the result i would like to re-create

[image]

Any idea of how to recreate this?
THANKS YOU!!

Comment: Please show us an example of the text and any code you have tried. Are the new lines built in or is the text just wrapping automatically?

Comment: Please share a code you've tried, So we can look into it and help you out.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```js
 function addIndices() {
     const textarea = document.getElementById('myTextArea');
     const lines = textarea.value.split('\n');
     const indexedLines = lines.map(function(line, index) {
          return '* ' + line;
     });
     document.getElementById('indexedText').textContent = indexedLines.join('\n');
}
```

```html
  <textarea id="myTextArea" oninput="addIndices()"></textarea>
<pre id="indexedText"></pre>
```